# Not firing dragend or mouseup when drag event is fired

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Getting stucked on dragging marker when releasing mouse button (to end the dragging) if only use

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Marker1,'drag',function() {Marker1.getPosition()})
```

but if I use

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Marker1,'dragend',function() {Marker1.getPosition()})
```

- all works fine and marker drops when I release the mouse button.

Want to use 'drag' for get dynamic position of marker while it beign dragged - not the result on dragend.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: what exactly is `Marker1.getPosition()` supposed to be doing?  It just returns a LatLng object, you don't seem to be doing anything with it

Comment: it sets the polygon point position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Marker1.getPosition()` will give you the final position of your marker.  During a drag, you want to use the [event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent)'s latLng property instead:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Marker1,'drag',function(e) {
    console.log(e.latLng);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! You`ve just healed my today`s headache!